# How to enforce exactly 1 space before blocks (space-before-blocks) with eslint?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier, js-beautify

the problem in vscode: eslint ignores extra spaces when fixing:

`function()           {` - i need exactly 1 space here.

the same happens with object notation:

`const test =          {  prop: true       };` -> `const test = {prop: true};` (doesnt work).

either there're some other rules to force proper formatting or eslint is pretty limited at formatting.

on the other hand i dont like prettier since it destroys empty lines
and js-beautify is limited in options also.

any suggestions how to fix this problem?

Comment: Those are not blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
'no-multi-spaces': ['error']
```